# Altura e largura SVG

Tags: javascript, svg

Tenho um elemento SVG e quero que a sua altura e largura se adequem conforme a resolução. Para isso vou obter em javascript através do screen.width.
Agora queria inserir esse valor obtido dentro da tag svg. É possível fazer isso?

```
<script>
 var window_width = screen.width;
 var window_height = screen.height;
</script>
<svg width="<script type='text/javascript'>screen.width</script>" height="500">
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10973339/modifying-svg-attributes-with-javascript-has-no-effect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pode fazer assim direto no js, segue abaixo modificação do seu código:

```
<svg id="xyz">

<script>
 var window_width = screen.width;
 var window_height = screen.height;

 var mySvg = document.getElementById("xyz");
 mySvg.style.width=window.width;
 mysvg.style.height=window_height;

</script>
```

Lembrando que o script deve vir abaixo da tag "svg"